# Solr 5.0.0 is not starting properly in CentOS

Tags: solr, lucene, centos, solrcloud

When I running command `bin/solr start -e cloud` it is not asking me to collection name and other information like no of replicas and configuration settings.

I got following output

```
Welcome to the SolrCloud example!


This interactive session will help you launch a SolrCloud cluster on your local workstation.

To begin, how many Solr nodes would you like to run in your local cluster? (specify 1-4 nodes) [2] 2
Ok, let's start up 2 Solr nodes for your example SolrCloud cluster.

Please enter the port for node1 [8983] 
8983
Please enter the port for node2 [7574] 
7574
Creating Solr home directory /home/webuser/abhijeet/solr-5.0.0/example/cloud/node1/solr
Cloning Solr home directory /home/webuser/abhijeet/solr-5.0.0/example/cloud/node1 into /home/webuser/abhijeet/solr-5.0.0/example/cloud/node2

Starting up SolrCloud node1 on port 8983 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983   



Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=23735). Happy searching!
```

Comment: try accessing  Solr Admin UI in your web browser: http://localhost:8983/solr/.  and check for more info. Its seems Solr running with two "nodes", one on port 7574 and one on port 8983. as you have asked for 2. There is one collection created automatically, 'gettingstarted', a two shard collection, each with two replicas. This is mentioned in the solr-5.0.0/example/cloud/node1/solr/gettingstarted_shard2_replica1/core.properties

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I checked using netstat command solr is running only on 8983 port but not on 7574 port. Admin page is not properly loaded on  [localhost:8983/solr].

Comment: [localhost:8983/solr]( [localhost:8983/solr]) showing **SolrCore Initialization Failure**

Comment: i tried it with solr5.0.0 and its working fine for me ...May be you just restart iit again n give a try

Comment: I also tried on ubuntu it woks in fine. But in centos it's not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it ...here it goes...only difference is I tried on Ubantu

```
abhijit@abhijit:~/Downloads/solr-5.0.0$ bin/solr start -e cloud 

Welcome to the SolrCloud example!


This interactive session will help you launch a SolrCloud cluster on your local workstation.

To begin, how many Solr nodes would you like to run in your local cluster? (specify 1-4 nodes) [2] 2
Ok, let's start up 2 Solr nodes for your example SolrCloud cluster.

Please enter the port for node1 [8983] 8983
Oops! Looks like port 8983 is already being used by another process. Please choose a different port. 8985
8985
Please enter the port for node2 [7574] 7576
7576

Starting up SolrCloud node1 on port 8985 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8985   


Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8985 [|]  
Started Solr server on port 8985 (pid=7092). Happy searching!



Starting node2 on port 7576 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node2/solr -p 7576 -z localhost:9985   


Waiting to see Solr listening on port 7576 [\]  
Started Solr server on port 7576 (pid=7461). Happy searching!


Now let's create a new collection for indexing documents in your 2-node cluster.

Please provide a name for your new collection: [gettingstarted] testCore
testCore
How many shards would you like to split testCore into? [2] 2
2
How many replicas per shard would you like to create? [2] 2
2
Please choose a configuration for the testCore collection, available options are:
basic_configs, data_driven_schema_configs, or sample_techproducts_configs [data_driven_schema_configs] data_driven_schema_configs
Connecting to ZooKeeper at localhost:9985
Uploading /home/abhijit/Downloads/solr-5.0.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf for config testCore to ZooKeeper at localhost:9985

Creating new collection 'testCore' using command:
http://127.0.1.1:7576/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=testCore&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=testCore

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":7468},
  "success":{"":{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":7057},
      "core":"testCore_shard1_replica2"}}}



SolrCloud example running, please visit http://localhost:8985/solr
```

[image: sole amdin page]

Comment: In CentOS, lsof is not installed, hence it is not working properly. Thanks :)

Comment: how did you figured it out about Isof is missing?

Comment: In bin/solr script, lsof is used