# Cannot Find Proper solrconfig.xml file for configuration in solr 5.1.0

Tags: java, php, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have setup **Solr** 4.7 before and I had configured *solrconfig.xml* file in my core for dataimport requestHandler and it was working fine.

But when I setup **Solr** 5.1.0, what is the location of *solrconfig.xml* file for particular core? Where is it located?

Comment: check at this path ../solr-5.1.0/example/example-DIH/solr/solr/conf

Comment: But I have created new core called **gettingstarted** in cloud mode with **2 nodes** and **2 shards**. I want to load MySQL data to this core. So that's why I want to do configuration in **gettingstarted** core's solrconfig.xml file.

Comment: check here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+solrconfig.xml

Comment: the statement "The solrconfig.xml file is located in the conf/ directory for each collection. Several well-commented example files can be found in the server/solr/configsets/ directories demonstrating best practices for many different types of installations.
"

Comment: try this command you will find your answer...                                          bin/solr start -e cloud                    also check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045712/solr-5-0-0-is-not-starting-properly-in-centos/30047598#30047598

Comment: I have setting up solr in SolrCloud mode with 2 nodes, 2 shards on 2 ports 5001 & 5002. By reading Reference guide of Solr 5.1.0, I came to know that SolrCloud config files are in Zookeeper folder to manage cloud cores on multiple port. So where to find this ZooKeeper folder?

Comment: Checkout this link please : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77176/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-mayur-champaneria).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try SolrCloud for the first time using the bin/solr -e cloud, the related configset gets uploaded to zookeeper automatically and is linked with the newly created collection.
The below command would start SolrCloud with the default collection name (gettingstarted) and default configset (data_driven_schema_configs) uploaded and linked to it.

here is the path for the config files

```
../solr-5.1.0/server/solr/configsets
```

if you don't mention the configset, the default is "data_driven_schema_configs".

So you will find your config files here

```
../solr-5.1.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs
```

Comment: This thing helps me. DataImportHandler changes affected. Thanks for this. 

But I cannot find **schema.xml** in this folder. How to I change schema related to my database?

Comment: the file is named as "managed-schema"... read the file ...This is the Solr schema file. This file should be named "schema.xml" and
 should be in the conf directory under the solr home
 (i.e. ./solr/conf/schema.xml by default) 
 or located where the classloader for the Solr webapp can find it.

Comment: Yah It has been solved. But I am configure that thing.